# What are the imagePath and apiRootUrl values when deploying a micro service using edgeSDK wrapper on iOS and how do I set them?

Tags: ios, swift, edgesdk, edgeengine

I'm working on an iOS application that uses a duktape javascript based micro service and will deploy it using edgeSDK's iOS wrapper. In order to do that I am asked to specify an imagePath and apiRootUrl values. What are they and how do I set them?

This is my deployment function:

```
func deployMicroService() -> Void {

    let deployConfig = MMKMicroserviceDeploymentConfig.init(name: "micro-service", apiRootUrl: "???", imagePath: "???", envVariables: [:])

    let edgeOpsWrapper = edgeSDK_iOS_app_ops()
    edgeOpsWrapper.deployMicroservice(edgeAccessToken: "MY-DEPLOYMENT-TOKEN", config: deployConfig) { (result) in

        if let checkedError = result.error {
            print("micro service deployment ended with error: \(checkedError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            print("micro service deployment result: \(result.status.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers are:

**apiRootUrl** is an arbitrary value that your micro service will be deployed under. For example you can use something like:

```
"/micro-service/v1"
```

and this would result for your micro service to be accessible at the following location:

```
http://localhost:8087/client-id-value/micro-service/v1
```

**imagePath** is a file system path to the micro service image tar file. Usually located in the application's bundle. For example you can use something like:

```
class func microServiceBundleStoragePath(serviceName: String) -> String? {
    let microServiceFileName = "\(serviceName)-v1"
    let microServiceBundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: microServiceFileName, ofType: ".tar")
    return microServiceBundlePath
}
```

resulting in a file system path of:

```
"/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DF2F6617-9153-4AEC-999D-BC7699A80FA0/example.app/micro-service-v1.tar"
```